# empty value checks for array_column

Tags: php

From the following array I can pull the last names by using `array_column` built in function of PHP. Now, My question is- Can I pull data if `last_name` is not empty?

```
$a = array(
  array(
    'id' => 5698,
    'first_name' => 'Peter',
    'last_name' => 'Griffin',
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 4767,
    'first_name' => 'Ben',
    'last_name' => ''
  )
);

$last_names = array_column($a, 'last_name');
print_r($last_names);
```

That means My output will be `Griffin`.

Comment: Using `array_filter()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do it by `array_diff`

```
<?php
$a = array(
  array(
    'id' => 5698,
    'first_name' => 'Peter',
    'last_name' => 'Griffin',
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 4767,
    'first_name' => 'Ben',
    'last_name' => ''
  )
);

$last_names = array_diff(array_column($a, 'last_name'),['']);
print_r($last_names);
?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/691720